# ContentResolver returns ALL media in external content instead of specific folders

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, mediastore

I am using ContentResolver to get media from external content by passing the URI to ContentResolver's query method. The problem is that I am getting back all files. How would I get specific folders, like "Downloads" or "Music"?

```
ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
```

When looping through the musicCursor object, should I perform an if check against a certain Environment constant, like Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC or Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS?

Comment: use third param to `query` method, something like: `String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ?";`

Comment: I guess 25% of an answer is better than 0%. Thanks.

Comment: how do you know it is 25%?

Comment: I think I know what I did wrong. I used an AND instead of an OR.

Comment: please don't drive and text, it's dangerous and probably illegal